# Wrong parent loop context in twig

Tags: loops, symfony, twig

I'm using Symfony 2.3 and Twig 1.15. I've got a nested foreach twig loop and I'm trying to get a different result for the last iteration of the outer loop.

I've seen this: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/recipes.html#accessing-the-parent-context-in-nested-loops
However I'm getting a different result - an error in the line where I access the parent context:

```
Key "loop" for array with keys "groups, scores, type, user, assetic, app, avatarsDir, sonata_block, _parent, _seq, group, _key, subgroup" does not exist in "(...)"
```

the relevant code, stripped of classes, ids and unnecessary tags:

```
{% for group in groups %}
    <div>
        {% for subgroup in group.subgroups %}
            {% for test in subgroup.tests %}
                {% block test_block_box %}
                    {% if not loop.parent.loop.last %}

                        (html follows...)

                    {% else %}

                        (some different html follows...)

                    {% endif %}
                {% endblock %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I have made sure that the error does not refer to the inner loop call, i.e. I replaced `loop.parent.loop.last` with `loop.last` and the page rendered successfully (contents obviously wrong, but it didn't crash).

What am I doing wrong when accessing the parent context??

Comment: Can you try without {% block %} in the loop? Maybe Twig have problems with determining the parent in a block.

Comment: Yes, this fixed the problem. Apparently the block instruction changes the context for Twig. Any idea if this is expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove `{% block test_block_box %}` and `{% endblock %}`, the loop parent shoud be accessible.

You can try to define a value outside of the `{% block %}` and see if you have access to it in the `{% block %}`:

```
{% for group in groups %}
    <div>
        {% for subgroup in group.subgroups %}
            {% for test in subgroup.tests %}
                {% set test_loop_is_last = loop.last %} {# define the value #}
                {% block test_block_box %}
                    {% if not test_loop_is_last %}{#test the value #}

                        (html follows...)

                    {% else %}

                        (some different html follows...)

                    {% endif %}
                {% endblock %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That's what I eventually did. Thanks a lot :)